# Inquisition and Item wc status

Tags: werewolv.es

How does the Inquisition's recruitment mechanic work when targeting non-wc village roles with items that do make them appear as wc-users?

(Extra question is more of a 'soft' one, since I know Inq wincon isn't coded: is the Inq's wincon dependant on people appearing as wc-users through items?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recruitment still works, even when the recruit is holding a rune.

Credit to: Shabas and Niji